# How to achieve strong parameter protection without Rails?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, strong-parameters, grape-api, goliath

I am developing a boilerplate web application with **Goliath + Grape + Active Record 4.2 + Active Record Migrations**. Here is my migration file

```
# db/migrate/20150519063210_create_albums.rb
class CreateAlbums < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :albums do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :artist
      t.string :genre
      t.date :published_at
    end
  end
end
```

And my model

```
# app/models/Album
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

And the Grape API

```
class ApiV1 < Grape::API
  version 'v1', using: :path
  format :json

  resource 'albums' do
    get '/' do
      Album.all
    end

    post '/' do
      Album.create(params[:album])  # <-- raises ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
    end
  end
end
```

When I call `POST /v1/albums/` with some parameters, the application always raises `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`. It seem that ActiveRecord wants `ActionController::Parameters` to be the arguments, but Grape gives it `Hashie::Mash`.

I've tried implementing a simple Rack middleware to convert `env['params']` from a `Hash` to a `ActionController::Parameters` and using it after `Goliath::Rack::Params`, but Grape just sanitizes it out when the helper method `params` is called. I also tried implementing and using a Grape middleware to do the same thing and got the same result.

Is there any solution on this or I just have to down grade to ActiveRecord 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a helper to generate an instance of `ActionController::Parameters` with your parameters:

```
require 'action_controller/metal/strong_parameters' 

class ApiV1 < Grape::API
  version 'v1', using: :path
  format :json

  helpers do
    def albums_params
      ActionController::Parameters.new(params).require(:album).permit(:attr1, :attr2)
    end
  end

  resource 'albums' do
    get '/' do
      Album.all
    end

    post '/' do
      Album.create(albums_params)
    end
  end
end
```

Or you can use the [hashie-forbidden_attributes](https://github.com/Maxim-Filimonov/hashie-forbidden_attributes) gem.

Comment: .update is not working. Can you please tell me how it will work?